# Whats the best way to determine availability or uptime of my systems

Tags: reporting, monitoring, uptime

By this I mean, whats the best way show the uptime of systems?  Idealy id like to show some sort of percentage figure,  like what the webhosts do.   ie  99.5% uptime.

Is there a standard way to determine this?

Comment: Yes, actually there's several ways to do this. make sure you use the right data for the right consumer though, there is a difference. Iv written a full article on it here, its called "Service Availability Reporting"
http://themonitoringguy.com/articles/service-availability-reporting/ That should answer your questions..

Comment: broken link to article

Comment: link to wayback machine version: https://web.archive.org/web/20160506183609/http://themonitoringguy.com/articles/service-availability-reporting

Comment: found it very helpful b/c it suggest an "outage" table where you subtract that from total time in the period. most advice i find assumes you have "time up in minutes/seconds/ms", but you dont generally have that. you have a sample of uptime (e.g. ping checks saying up/down). If you think of instead storing downs as an "incident" it really simplifies the development. at least it has for me.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/) to monitor our servers, and they generate the sort of numbers you're looking for (we just use the free account).  They also seem to have an [API](http://www.pingdom.com/services/api/) which will let you get your info programatically - no guarantees that'll work with a free account, though.

Hope this helps!